# Recover Linux ext4 partition formatted(erased) to hfs+

Tags: linux, macos, ext4, partition-recovery, hfs+

I have a Linux partition with ext4 and I accidentally formatted it with Mac OS X Disk Utility to HFS+ (Mac OS X Extended Journaled).

I tried to recover it with http://www.r-studio.com/ on Windows but I can't get any files except few from trash or temporary browser files.

Now I'm trying another software on OS X: http://www.stellarinfo.com/mac-data-recovery.htm, however it takes some time to scan partitions.

Any ideas how to recover that partition? Should I recover it on Linux or Mac?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try "Scalpel" it may be help. Scalpel is an open source file system recovery.
for more information follow below link:
http://www.tecmint.com/install-scalpel-a-filesystem-recovery-tool-to-recover-deleted-filesfolders-in-linux/